# touchesBegan not called on UICollectionView subclass

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, touch, uigesturerecognizer

I have subclassed `UICollectionView` as `CoolGridCollectionView` and I have overrides the `touchesBegan:` and `touchesEnded:` methods. But those are not getting called, when I tap the cell. And that cells are having single and double tap gesture recognisers. I need the position, where the tap has happened. I can get the position by using `covertPoint:` something else. But Why the touches methods are not called? Does iOS handles touches of `UICollectionView` specifically.

Comment: add Gesture in windows, you get Touch

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% sure, but you can try hitTest:withEvent: method instead of -touchesBegan:withEvent: method. Hope this will helpful to you.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    touchedView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    NSSet* touches = [event allTouches];
    // handle touches if you need
    return touchedView;
}
```